# Display Progress message after calling api url

Tags: url-routing

we select checbox & onclick button "**Show Status**" , I am calling external webservice api url & updating the "**status**" column [4th in below image] values in Database.....

once we got **success** response we are displaying **alert message**....

[image]

**Requirement** :

but now i want to display Progress like **"1% completed , 2 % completed"** , so on.... :

[image]

**status page**

```
<button type= "button" id="show_status" >Show Status</button>
```

**script**

```
$('#show_status').click(function()
 { 
    var selected = []; 
    $('.assigneeid-order:checked').each(function() 
       { 
         selected.push($(this).val()); 
         $('.assigneeid-order').prop('checked', false);
       }); 

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(selected); 

$.ajax
  ({ 
type: "POST", 
url: "api.php", 
data: {data : jsonString}, 
     success: function(response)
       { 
          response = $.parseJSON(response);
          alert("completed");
          $.each(response, function(index, val)
             { 

                   $("#"+index+"").html(val);
                   $("#"+index+"").html(val.status); 

             }); 
        } 
  }); 

});
```

**api.php**

```
 <?php

$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data'])); 
$response = array(); 

foreach($data as $id){ 

$post_data['username']='a';
$url = 'https://plapi.ecomexpress.in/track_me/api/mawbd/'; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_close($ch); 

$orderResults=$xml=simplexml_load_string($output);
//print_r($orderResults); die;
    foreach($orderResults->object as $child)
    {
      $status=(string)$child->field[10];         
      break;
     }

$statusfinal = str_replace('<field type="CharField" name="status">','',$status); 

if($statusfinal!='') 
{ 
$sqlecom = "UPDATE do_order set in_transit='".$status."' where tracking_id=".$orderid;
//echo $sqlecom;

$db_handleecom = new DBController(); 
$resultecom = $db_handleecom->executeUpdate($sqlecom); 
} 
$response[$orderid] = [ 'status' => $status ];
}
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: i got that i need to use `(numberOfFinishedRequests / numberOfRequest) * 100;` but not getting how to implement in script.......

Comment: Do you have these records in db ( numberOfFinishedRequests  & numberOfRequest ), if so then you can send another parameter with status like calculated percentage with response and in Jquery make a progress bar out of it or can show simple percenteage as you may like.

Comment: @kshitij sorry , yes, we will save the status of particular rows once it update....

Comment: @kshitij `numberOfRequest` = `how many rows we will select` - we have this value in DB [ total rows ] ,  `numberOfFinishedRequests` = `how many rows already updated` , once rows are updated, we will save in DB...... using that can we calculate percentage ?

Comment: Are you trying to get percentage according to total rows or just percentage according to already updated ones?  If its according to total then
 numberofRequest% = (numberOfRequest/ TotalRequest ) * 100

Comment: @kshitij `total rows selected` - 100 [ value there in DB ]   , `number of rows already updated` - 50 [ once it updated we are saving in DB ] , so i want to display result : 50 %.....

Comment: @kshitij so (50/100)*100 = 50 %......

Comment: @kshitij so we already have `total rows selected - totalnumberofrequest` value in DB, but how to find out `numberOfFinishedRequests` ?

Comment: yup if going through this you are right  :   (number of rows updated/total rows selected) * 100                    this will give you the right percentage as here total will be the selected rows and you are getting % with respect to that amount.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184791/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-kshitij).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this script and code

```
$('#show_status').click(function()
 { 
    var selected = []; 
    $('.assigneeid-order:checked').each(function(){ 
        selected.push($(this).val()); 
        $('.assigneeid-order').prop('checked', false);
    }); 
    var count = selected.length
    var perPlush = 100/count;
    var per = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        $.ajax
        ({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "api.php", 
            data: {id : selected[i]},               
            success: function(response)
            { 
                response = $.parseJSON(response);
                $.each(response, function(index, val)
                { 
                    $("#"+index+"").html(val);
                    $("#"+index+"").html(val.status); 
                });
                per = per + perPlush;
                console.log(Math.round(per) + " % Complated");
                $("#progress").html(Math.round(per) + " % Complated"); 
            } 
        });     
    }
});
```

Your api.php file

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL & ~MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);

require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();




$id = $_POST['id']; //960856092
$response = array(); 

$orderid = $id; 
$hide = '';
$post_data['awb']=$orderid;  
$url = 'https://plapi.ecomexpress.in/track_me/api/mawbd/'; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://plapi.ecomexpress.in/track_me/api/mawbd/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
$output = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

$orderResults=$xml=simplexml_load_string($output);
if($orderResults){
    foreach($orderResults->object as $child)
    {
        $status=(string)$child->field[10];       
        break;
    }

    $statusfinal = str_replace('<field type="CharField" name="status">','',$status); 

    if($statusfinal!='') 
    { 
    $sqlecom = "UPDATE do_order set in_transit='".$status."' where tracking_id=".$orderid;
    //echo $sqlecom;

    $db_handleecom = new DBController(); 
    $resultecom = $db_handleecom->executeUpdate($sqlecom); 
    } 
    $response[$orderid] = [ 'status' => $status ];  
}
else{
    $response[$orderid] = ['status' => 'Order already placed'];
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: for some rows, i am getting error `Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: status in <b>/var/www/html/ecom/api.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: status in <b>/var/www/html/ecom/api.php</b> on line <b>54</b><br />
{"100290150":{"status":null}}`

Comment: Add $status= ' ';
before $orderResults=$xml=simplexml_load_string($output);
api.php

Comment: but i checked in api server, results are there in their server : https://ecomexpress.in/tracking/?awb_field=960741834

Comment: Please add this code to 
$response[$orderid] = ['status' => $status]; 
add after 
$orderResults=$xml=simplexml_load_string($output);

Comment: Please change $status = '' to $status='your msg' when api getting false

Comment: sure, i will add it, please give me 2 minutes, i kept for some 8000 rows, i will try once it complete......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184863/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-raju-sadadiya).